# Playing, recording, and streaming sound with cat and /dev/dsp

Tags: audio, freebsd, cat, netcat, microphone

A couple of comments on Hacker News suggest that, on FreeBSD, you can:

1. use `cat` to send a file ( a `.wav` file for instance ) to the audio
   speaker (`/dev/dsp`).
2. record from the mic using a similar method.
3. send a live stream across the network (using `netcat`?)

I can nearly do the first one. I do `cat /dev/random > /dev/dsp` and it makes white noise. Can't work out how to record that to a file. And 2 and 3 I can't figure out. Any ideas?

https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=28054789

https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=28055498

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `cat somefile.wav > /dev/dsp`
2. `cat /dev/dsp > record_from_mic.wav`
3. `cat /dev/dsp | nc -l 1234`